# Python type() shows different results

Tags: python, sublimetext2

I'm using `Sublime Text 2` while learning Python, actually I'm just a beginner. Now, when I write `type(1/2)` in editor and build it(**cmd+B**), I get the output as **int**. Instead if I write the same instruction in Sublime's terminal(**ctrl + `** ), I get the result as **float**. Can somebody explain me why does that happen?

```
type(1/2) #in Sublime's editor results: <type 'int'>
type(1/2) #in Sublime's python console results <type 'float'>
```

I believe it should be "**int**", but still why does that say "**float**".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Somewhere the code is importing from `__future__.division`

```
>>> type(1/2)
<type 'int'>
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> type(1/2)
<type 'float'>
```

`python2.7`

```
>>> type(1/2)
<type 'int'>
```

Python 3 has type report this as a class so it's not the interpreter using python3.

`python3`

```
>>> type(1/2)
<class 'float'>
```

Comment: [If this answers your question then please accept the answer.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109956/is-it-important-to-say-thanks-after-getting-correct-answer)

Comment: I was just waiting to see, if I would get any other answers explaining the question. Any how, you answered me.

Comment: Sorry to pressure you then.